# rounded Corner Problems IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, rounded-corners

I rounded Div Corner Using This Htc File :
[Google Code Curved Corner](http://code.google.com/p/curved-corner/)

This Worked Nice in IE6/8 but i set background image in top my div with no-repeat css. now i see my background auto repeat in div. ( with htc file without this worked nice )

```
    width:860px;
margin:0 auto;
margin:10px 0 10px 0;
float:right;
border:#e1e1e1 1px solid;
background:url(images/wrapper.png) top center no-repeat;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-khtml-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
    behavior: url(border.htc);
```

This My Code, How To fix This Problem !?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

see below the link.

http://css3pie.com/

PIE makes Internet Explorer 6-8 capable of rendering several of the most useful CSS3 decoration features.

This is useful for you.

Comment: css3pie is 33kb! for each rounded corner load 33kb ! 5 div * 33kb This Is Crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your css:

```
-ms-border-radius: 6px;
```

Instead of using the .htc file...

Comment: lol! you read my question ?!! i need to fix rounded corner for ie 6+ not ie9+ ( support css 3 and border radius )

Comment: With This Same Problem repaet background.

Comment: @Aseman: Have you tried setting the background repeat separately, and marking it important? Like this: `background-repeat:no-repeat !important;`

Comment: <img src="http://s2.picofile.com/file/7117087739/test.png" width="100" height="100">